# Get the checked value

Tags: php, jquery, prestashop

When I check my box on the left, I would like to retrieve the value in an input field and when I uncheck it it removes the value from the field. But it should also be that when I check several checkboxes it adds all the values ​​in the input field and separates the data with a comma. How is it possible to do this? Here is what my code looks like.

My JS

```
 function checkedUsers() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(
        function () {
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.product-message').val();
            } else {
                $('.product-message').val($(this).val());
            }
        });
}
```

My tpl (smarty)

```
{foreach from=$familyUser item=user}
    {if $user.active == 1 && {math equation="floor(age / 365)" age=$user.age} <= 16}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{$user.id_block_family}" id="userChecked" name="userChecked[]" onclick="checkedUsers();">
                        {$user.surname|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} {$user.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Side note, the conditional in your each() doesn't make logical sense.  You selected checkboxes that are checked, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to do this is to simply rebuild the value each time, from the checkboxes that are still checked.  That way you do not have to keep track of which value was removed.

```js
function checkedUsers() {
  //set the value to all the selected values, separated by a comma
  $('.product-message').val(
    $(":checkbox:checked").map(function(){ return this.value; }).get().join(', ')
  );
}
```

Comment: On the off chance you will not have an idea to add the submission of the form automatically when check? thx

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking, but that sounds like a different question than what you asked originally, and should possibly be another question.

Comment: Yes indeed it is another question.